# How to specify a regression model with a time-varying predictor and time-varying outcome?

Tags: regression, repeated-measures, panel-data, time-varying-covariate

I'm trying to specify a regression model. The data spans 6 time periods in a patient population. Periods 1-3 are blood glucose samples, and 4-6 are troponin samples (cardiac damage marker). So, a conditional growth model considering only the time-varying predictor in R would be, I think:

```
troponin ~ glucose*time_period + (time_period|patient)
```

assuming data in long format:

| patient | time_period | glucose | troponin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | NA |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | NA |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | NA |
| 1 | 4 | NA | 10 |
| 1 | 5 | NA | 23 |
| 1 | 6 | NA | 7 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | 10 |

and so on...

So, I've got 2 problems:

1. How do I reformat the data to handle separation of the predictor and outcome in the time dimension?
2. How do specify a model handling time variation (and autocorrelation) in both predictor and outcome? Could I do that with a multilevel model?

Comment: Are there actually any trends in the glucose or troponin levels across time in their 3 measurements each? This looks like you might just have replicate measurements that happened to be taken sequentially. Please edit the question to provide more details about the time spans involved and the hypothesis that you want to test about the relationship between glucose and troponin.